# НаряжАние и наряжЕние

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, существительные

*Наряж**а**ние* и *наряж**е**ние* ― есть такие слова?

Answer (score 2):

Наряж/а/ть — наряж/а/ни/е.

Существительное образуется от глагола несовершенного вида,  так как обозначает процесс, а не конечный результат.

Хотя слово используется в языке не часто (оно не кажется благозвучным, отчасти напрягает слух), но определенная потребность в нем есть, например : "Понятие «правильно» к наряжанию елки не совсем приемлемо" (запись в Интернете).

Примечание. В словарной статье к глаголу  нарядить/наряжать это существительное не указывается (Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года).

Возможно, эту форму следует отнести к разговорной.

В Нацкорпусе только один пример:

...то же наряжание себя в самые нарядные платья, то же пристрастие к сладкой еде...  [Л. Н. Толстой. Христианство и патриотизм (1894)]

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на какой-то словарь (это хорошо, конечно), но не указываете, на какой. А в других словарях это слово (**наряжение**) есть (см. толковый словарь Ефремовой, например, — там указано два значения, с пометкой "разговорное"). Более того, поиск по гугло-книгам показывает, что в научной литературе, посвящённой народным обычаям, это слово встречается довольно часто и, очевидно, не в разговорном стиле.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на словарь. Все реквизиты указывать не обязательно :) Ещё здесь принято (просто это всем привычно и удобно) ссылку на словарь Кузнецова делать через Грамоту: [нарядить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше внимание.  У Ефремовой информация не очень ясна, как и разговорность стиля. https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/309674.html А научная литература по народным обычаям - это специальная тема (не общеупотребительная лексика).

Comment: У Ефремовой выделено в [отдельную словарную статью](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/309676.html). По поводу общеупотребительной лексики: Вы ведь не знаете, кто и с какой целью спрашивает и кто потом будет читать. Сюда может зайти аспирант, пишущий статью, или школьник, решивший, что он нашёл ошибку у профессора :)

Comment: Как-то сложно работать со словарем Ефремовой, да еще онлайн  Два многозначных глагола,  связанных видовыми отношениями,  два существительных, к ним отнесенных. И всё это в разных статьях. Придется присоединиться к аспиранту и спросить: "Наряжание, наряжение. Есть такое слово?"

Answer (score 0):

У Даля под словом [НАРЯЖАТЬ](http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=18345):

> **Наряжанье** ср. длит. наряженье окончат. наряд м. нарядка ж. действие по глаг. на ть и на ся. При **наряжаньи** поссорились было, а по наряженьи (нарядившись) поехали мирно. Во время наряжанья подвод было много шуму, спору, а по наряженьи все отправились.

У Ефремовой:

[НАРЯЖЕНИЕ](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/309676.html)
ср.
Процесс действия по знач. глаг.: наряжать (2*), нарядить (2*).

На Грамоте:

> Вопрос № 298959
>   Наряжание, наряжение. Есть такое слово?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   От глагола наряжать можно образовать существительное **наряжание**.

В Нацкорпусе:

> Все же мы опоздали на обряд **наряжения** быка, которого под песни ансамбля «Торама» провели по селу и принесли в жертву Инешкипазу. [Николай Аношкин. Зов Торамы (2000) // «Жизнь национальностей», 2000.03.24]
>
> После этого начинается церемония **наряжения** птицы, туалет которой состоит из немалого количества с ювелирным мастерством выполненных деталей. [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по русскому искусству (2000)]
>
> Особенность этого соблазна состоит в том, что во имя его совершаются самые дикие и бессмысленные поступки, вроде **наряжения** себя в особенные, странные одежды и приписывания этим одеждам особенного значения, и поступки вроде отравления себя вином, пивом, и очень часто во имя этого же соблазна, вызывающего враждебность одних товариществ к другим, совершаются страшно жестокие поступки ― драки, дуэли, убийства и т. п. [Л. Н. Толстой. Христианское учение (1896)]
>
> Сказать им, как ей совестно было за себя и за них, это значило выдать свое волнение; кроме того отказаться от **наряжения**, которое предлагали ей, повело бы к продолжительным шуткам и настаиваниям. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том первый (1867-1869)]

---

> Эту горжетку, честно говоря, она и надела-то в дорогу не столько для того, чтобы предстать перед любимым и повоевавшим мужем во всей привлекательности и шикарности, тем более, что именно он ей перед самой войною эту вещь и купил из своих отличных инженерских зарплат, ― кажется, чуть ли не четыреста рублей в месяц, ― что, впрочем, могло бы быть такой дополнительной причиной рискованного **наряжания** в дорогу , как доказательство верности и памяти, ― если бы главная причина не была более практической: она допускала обмен меха на билет или еду, если в пути уж совсем туго придется. [Александр Кабаков. Последний герой (1994-1995)]
>
> То же необыкновенное благодушие, переходящее в беспричинную и радостную экзальтацию, та же сентиментальность, утрированная учтивость, говорливость, те же беспрестанные слезы умиления, приходящие и проходящие без причинны, то же праздничное настроение, то же гуляние и посещение друг друга, то же **наряжание** себя в самые нарядные платья, то же пристрастие к сладкой еде, те же бессмысленные речи, та же праздность, то же пение и музыка,то же руководительство женщин и та же для многих клоуническая фаза attitudes passionells, которую заметил г-н Сикорский у малеванцев, т.е. [Л. Н. Толстой. Христианство и патриотизм (1894)]
>
> что можно, предаваясь объедению, **наряжанию**, физической праздности, даже блуду, быть вполне хорошим, полезным человеком. [Л. Н. Толстой. Первая ступень (1891)]